# Where are all the Amazon EC2 micro AMIs?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'd like to take advantage of Amazon's offer of free micro EC2 servers. I'm browsing through public AMIs, but any public AMI that I try to launch requires a minimum of "small" instance - I don't find any AMI that allows a micro instance.

How can I find public AMIs that support a micro instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for AMIs that make use of EBS backed storage rather than ones that rely on instance storage (because micro instances have no instance store).

Answer (score 1):

If you browse through the AWS Console, the instances that are eligible for the free tier (Linux, < 10Gb, EBS) are marked with a little star.

If you are looking for an app like Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress, etc. all BitNami apps [are freely available as micros](http://bitnami.org/stacks/)  Just click on the app icon and scroll down.